# Move onclick function to JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning basics of JS so bare with with.

I have this link:

```
<a href="#comment" onclick="window.location.hash = 'comment'; document.getElementById('comment').focus(); return false;" id="to-comment">Leave a comment</a>
```

I want to move that onclick to my JS file in a function. To do this, I have:

```
jQuery("#to-comment").click(function() {

    window.location.hash='comment';

    document.getElementById('comment').focus();

    return false;

});
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: To clarify my question: How do I move that onclick function successfully into my JS file?

See this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zry1fxp3/).

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Did you include jQuery and use a document.ready function as well ?

Comment: @adeneo Can you show me how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: by including the `href="#comment"`, the browser will automatically change the `window.location.hash` for you when clicking that link as long as you don't `return false` in your callback. You might consider removing the `window.location.hash = 'comment'` because that will occur automatically and also remove the `return false` as that only prevents the `hash =` from occurring automatically for you.

Comment: `window.location.hash='comment';` it doesnt makes any sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated:**

What I've ended up with is this:

```
$("#to-comment").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#comment textarea').focus();
    }, 1);
});
```

html:

```
<div id="comment">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
...
<a href="#comment" id="to-comment">Leave a comment</a>
```

It seems that Firefox is conflicted about `focus`ing after the `hashchange` event because it has just traveled to the anchor in the href and applied focus to it. A second attempt at focusing is not producing any results as it's protecting against focus hijacking.

To circumvent this, we can add the `comment` ID to an element that does not "hold" focus (like a div). That way, the focus can be changed after traveling to that anchor.

I still found that `setTimeout` is necessary to add the focus attempt to the end of the execution stack so as not to occur during the lifecycle of the hashchange + focus event occuring after clicking the `<a href="#comment"...`.

I've run the fiddle in firefox, safari and chrome and it seems to be okay. Without javascript, the anchor should work as expected.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jbuw058z/12/

Comment: There appears to be one final issue. Without window.location.hash = 'comment'; -- the screen will not go down to the textarea properly, only to the field. To demonstrate this, see, on FF, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/jbuw058z/3/ and then this: https://jsfiddle.net/jbuw058z/5/ -- The good news is that adding window.location solves it for Firefox, but then breaks it for Safari. Any solution to this?

Comment: While the jsfiddle works fine on Safari, it appears that on the live site, it works only if you reclick the link (once the URL bar has #comment in it). Otherwise, it takes you to the textarea but does not focus in it so you can instantly start typing. To think that this basic thing would end up being such a task to solve. Any ideas to why it is behaving like this and possible solution?

Comment: I think the issue here is that changing the window hash scrolls to **and applies focus to** the element with that `#comment` id, which happens to be an element that can accept focus and hold onto it. However, once the focus has been set to the textarea via the `hashchange`, the browser is disallowing the focus to be changed yet again (to protect against focus hijacking?).

Thus, we're left with a focused item which the focus cannot be taken away from (in this instance, to place the cursor in the textarea and be able to type.

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue is present on the main site. I believe the reason is because I have a different function set on the #comment textarea. When user .focus() on it, the name/email inputs .fadeIn() -- I believe this conflicts on Safari. Thank you nonetheless for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The code is not wrapped in `ready`. This might be the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#to-comment').on('click', function() {
        window.location.hash='comment';
        $('#comment').focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it did not focus on the #comment textarea.

Comment: If the js script is placed after the anchor tag there is no need for `ready`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson DId you check if the `click` event is fired?

Answer (score 1):

This should be your link:

```
<a href='javascript: ;' id='to-comment'>Leave a comment</a>
```

The `href='javascript: ;'` runs an empty javascript snippet, hense does nothing.

And this should be your Javascript:

```
$( '#to-comment' ).click(function() {
  window.location.hash = 'comment';  //Equivalent to a href='#comment'
  document.getElementById( 'comment' ).focus();
});
```

If you have'nt already you would need to wrap the previous JavaScript in:

```
$(function() {
  //Previous code
});
```

**P.S** This hasn't been tested

Comment: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbuw058z/ -- we were thinking the same thing

Comment: @jbielick Your jsfiddle does not focus on the textarea. When user clicks the link, it should focus on it. See this jsfiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/zry1fxp3/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson going to have to disagree with you: http://i.imgur.com/szauVYH.gif

Comment: @jbielick Oh right, please try your fiddle in Firefox, it doesn't work there. It works in Safari/Chrome..

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I updated my answer, it now works in what I beleive all browsers

Comment: @Dendromaniac Unfortunately, doesn't work on Firefox. Works on Safari though.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson It does work for me, I'm using latest FF: https://jsfiddle.net/dj2dr02a/

Comment: sounds like FF has issues focusing during the `hashchange` event, simplest solution: `setTimeout(function() { $('#comment').focus(); }, 1};`  https://jsfiddle.net/jbuw058z/2/

Comment: @jbielick Nice. Can you please post this in a separate answer. While Den's works, I need the hash in the A tag for users who have JS disabled.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson can do

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use some other tag and not `a` tag for ex.

```
<span href="#comment" id="to-comment">Leave a comment</span>
```